# Advection equation for a gradient and higher order derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, lie-derivative

If a scalar function $\phi$ satisfy the advection equation
$$
\partial_t \phi + v_k \partial_k \phi = 0,
$$
where $v_k$ is some vector field. Then the gradient $\partial_i \phi$ satisfy the following advection equation
$$
\partial_t \partial_i \phi + v_k \partial_i \partial_k \phi + (\partial_i v_k) \partial_k \phi = 0.
$$

With the help of Lie derivative we can rewrite the above equations as
\begin{align}
\partial_t \phi + \mathcal{L}_v \phi 
&=
0,
\\
\partial_t \nabla \phi + \mathcal{L}_v \nabla \phi 
&=
0.
\end{align}

What about the second derivative(Hessian) $\nabla^2 \phi$, what equation does it satisfy? I did the calculation in coordinates and I got
$$
\partial_t \nabla^2 \phi + \mathcal{L}_v \nabla^2 \phi 
= - \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla^2 v,
$$
just to clarify, we have $(\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla^2 v)_{ij} = (\partial_k \phi)(\partial_i \partial_j v_k)$.

Is there a nice way how to derive the equation for $\nabla^2 \phi$ without doing the calculation in coordinates? Does it scale to higher derivatives?

Comment: How can you dot a vector with a scalar in $\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla^{2} v$?

Comment: I was expecting that the notation might be confusing, that is why I wrote an explicit formula in coordinates: $(\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla^2 v)_{ij} = (\partial_k \phi)(\partial_i \partial_j v_k)$. Note, that $v$ is a vector, its second derivative $\nabla^2 v$ is a rank three tensor and $\nabla \phi$ is a vector.